# CodeMirror bind C-d as scroll down

Tags: codemirror

I am currently using CodeMirror in LeetCode and I realized Ctrl-b is binded as scroll up but Ctrl-d is binded as delete as opposed to scroll down.

Is there a way to fix this in my developer console?

I am using CodeMirror specifically in LeetCode.com

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Commands are defined by adding properties to the `CodeMirror.commands` object.

You can override the `deleteLine` property like so:

```
CodeMirror.commands.deleteLine = function() {
  console.log('hello');
};
```

[CodeMirror Commands](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#commands)